# Styling PostGIS data in MapInfo

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapinfo, style

I have loaded data from a MapInfo TAB file into PostGIS using EasyLoader. I can view the data in MapInfo now, except that the feature-based styles are being ignored.

When I look at the map catalogue, I can see that it specifies the `MI_STYLE` column  as the column to use for styling, but this seems to be ignored by MapInfo.

I'm using MapInfo v15, Postgres 9.5 and PostGIS 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the MI_STYLE column for the table in PostgreSQL. Does the column contain any data at all or is it empty/NULL?

If that's the case, MapInfo Pro will use the default style for the table stored in MapInfo_MapCatalog. It will only store a style in the column if the style is different to the default style of the table.

You can also try to change the style on a single feature in MapInfo Pro and save the changes back to the table (and to the database). Now refresh the table. If the style sticks to the feature that you changed the style on, it works. If it doesn't MapInfo Pro is ignoring the MI_STYLE column.